# Windows Driver can't build normally

Tags: windows, driver

When I complile Windows Driver, I got an error and it shows in the image. I wonder how caused such this error and how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcptT.png)

When I choose `Release` and `x64` option, I got this unexpected error but with `Debug` and `x64` options, I did not get any error.

I try create a new project to compile it. At first it can work normally, but after a while, I get this error consistently. I didn't change config files or configuration options without any doubt. Now only solution is change the configuration to `x64&Debug`.

Does anybody have the same problem? I would appreciate it very much!

I searched in Google and MSDN, but did not find any results...

Comment: change one setting at a time on your debug to match release until it fails. Then you'll know

Comment: I got it,maybe it is a bug on VS2017.I found a steady way to  reemerge.I create two project in one solution,one is windows driver project,another is ring3 program.If I compile ring3 program first,I will fail to compile windows driver if I choose Realease & x64 option.But I clear the ring3 program project,it can complie magically.